# Missing $ inserted. \If Missing } inserted. \If {$

Tags: algorithms

What's wrong with following algorithm?

```
\documentclass{ws-ijseke}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{zed-csp}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Initialization}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require  Source Code of a Software Systems $S$
        \Ensure List of MMR suggestions those do not break applications after refactoring
        \State $A \gets$ AST of $S$
        \State $M$ $\leftarrow$ List of methods from $A$
        \State $RClass$ $\leftarrow$ List of Regular classes of $S$
        \State $TClass$ $\leftarrow$ List of UnitTest classes of $S$
        \State $LMMRS$ $\leftarrow$ $\emptyset$
        \For {($m$ $\in$ $M$)}
        \State $maxCallFromTarget \gets 0$\
            \For {($t$ $\in$ $RClass$)}
             \If {$t$ != $m.sourceClass$}
                \State $callFromTarget$ $\leftarrow$ Number of entities $m$ uses from $t$
                \If {$maxCallFromTarget$ $<$ $callFromTarget$}
                    \State $m.targetClass$ $\leftarrow$ $t$
                    \State $maxCallFromTarget$ $\leftarrow$ $callFromTarget$
                \EndIf
             \EndIf
            \EndFor
        \EndFor

    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

I am getting following errors:

- Missing $ inserted.
- \If Missing } inserted.
- \If {$ Extra }, or forgotten $.
- \If {$t$ != $m.sourceClass$}

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Comment: \documentclass{ws-ijseke}

Comment: The `ws-ijseke` document class does not appear to be distributed with TeXLive, which is one of the major TeX distributions. Is `ws-ijseke` available online somewhere?

Comment: Also please complete the MWE, there are no `\begin/end{document}` statements

Comment: @Mico It's a journal template. You can find it here https://www.worldscientific.com/page/ijseke/submission-guidelines

Comment: @daleif I did not place full code here. My file includes \begin/end{document}

Comment: the `zed-csp` package should probably not be used. It has not been updated since '95 and is redefining `\If` etc to be incompatible with the algorithm stuff.

Comment: You're basically wasting our time the the example you post is not something we can just copy and paste and use right away. Thus people will walk away from helping you. Similarly, when you're using a non standard class, the first thing youi do is test it with a standard class like `article` to rule out the class. In this case the class does not matter.

Comment: @daleif I have tried removing `zed-csp`

Comment: Adding the document env, removing `zed-csp` and switching to `article` and your example compiles just fine for me.

Comment: It compiles fine for me using `article` (but there's no need to comment out `zed-csp` to make it compile). It does _not_ compile if I use the `standalone` class, which suggests that `algpseudocode` is implicitly assuming some other package is loaded...

Comment: @rbrignall no `zed-csp` defines `\If` in a manner different to how we use it in algorithms. The algorithm does not defined `\If` if it is already defined.

Comment: Oh, wait, it was only compiling for me because `\If` was commented out. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

Not nice, but its something...

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\let\aif\If
\usepackage{zed-csp}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Initialization}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require  Source Code of a Software Systems $S$
        \Ensure List of MMR suggestions those do not break applications after refactoring
        \State $A \gets$ AST of $S$
        \State $M$ $\leftarrow$ List of methods from $A$
        \State $RClass$ $\leftarrow$ List of Regular classes of $S$
        \State $TClass$ $\leftarrow$ List of UnitTest classes of $S$
        \State $LMMRS$ $\leftarrow$ $\emptyset$
        \For {($m$ $\in$ $M$)}
        \State $maxCallFromTarget \gets 0$\
            \For {($t$ $\in$ $RClass$)}
             \aif {$t$ != $m.sourceClass$}
                \State $callFromTarget$ $\leftarrow$ Number of entities $m$ uses from $t$
                \aif {$maxCallFromTarget$ $<$ $callFromTarget$}
                    \State $m.targetClass$ $\leftarrow$ $t$
                    \State $maxCallFromTarget$ $\leftarrow$ $callFromTarget$
                \EndIf
             \EndIf
            \EndFor
        \EndFor

    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

First load algorithm, copy the macro, then load zed-csp.

Result:

[image]